# In Makefile, know if GNU make is in --dry-run?

Tags: gnu-make

Is there any way to know in a `Makefile` whether GNU make was called with the `--dry-run` option?

I'm looking for something like:

```
ifeq (dry-run)
    ; # do not create a rule
else
    ; # create a custom rule
endif
```

This could also be any other workaround.

Reason for this is that I reference rules from another `Makefile` that rely on a `.PHONY` target and hence with dry-run it displays all targets and not only outdated ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can examine the value of `MAKEFLAGS` to see which flags are set.  If the `-n` option is present then you know make is running in dry run mode (`MAKEFLAGS` always contains the short single character option, if one exists, regardless of which option was specified on the command line).

Something like this:

```
ifeq (n,$(findstring n,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS))))
  # run with -n / --dry-run
else
  # not run with -n / --dry-run
endif
```

Comment: Does this work for `make --recon;`?

Comment: Well, it's probably faster to just try it than to ask us and wait for an answer.  But the answer is "yes".  All options that have single-letter variations are put into `MAKEFLAGS` as their single-letter variants, in the first argument.  This is documented as of GNU make 4.0.  `echo '$(info $(MAKEFLAGS))' | make --recon -f-` gives `n`.

Comment: Your answer is much better than anything I could have gotten by experimentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Based on @madscientist reponse, if the command you want to optionally execute also supports also `-n` switch (e.g. `rsync`), you can short-circuit the command like this:

```
_n := $(findstring -n,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS)))

foo:
    rsync $(_n)  ...
```

Comment: This won't quite work because `MAKEFLAGS` could easily contain other options before `n`; in that case `-n` wouldn't be found.  You can do something like `_n := $(if $(findstring n,$(firstword -$(MAKEFLAGS))),-n)`